# ElasticSeach mapping getting error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hi i am trying to putmapping through python-elastic-search.I want to add case intensive mapping in my code. Please check the mapping and help me out. getting 500 Transport error not_x_content_exception.

```
    mapping = '''
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_keyword": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "countrycpm": {
            "properties": {
                "uid": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "country": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "cpm": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "createdby": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "updatedby": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "createddate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                },
                "updateddate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                },
                "status = mode": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "createdbyname": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "updatedbyname": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'''

els.indices.put_mapping(index = ES_INDEX, doc_type = 'countrycpm',body=json.dumps(mapping))
```

Response

```
    TransportError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-4c3baa9096ca> in <module>()
----> 1 els.indices.put_mapping(index = ES_INDEX, doc_type = 'countrycpm',body=json.dumps(map))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.pyc in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     67                 if p in kwargs:
     68                     params[p] = kwargs.pop(p)
---> 69             return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
     70         return _wrapped
     71     return _wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.pyc in put_mapping(self, doc_type, body, index, params)
    289                 raise ValueError("Empty value passed for a required argument.")
    290         _, data = self.transport.perform_request('PUT', _make_path(index,
--> 291             '_mapping', doc_type), params=params, body=body)
    292         return data
    293 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.pyc in perform_request(self, method, url, params, body)
    305 
    306             try:
--> 307                 status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
    308 
    309             except TransportError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.pyc in perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, ignore)
     91         if not (200 <= response.status < 300) and response.status not in ignore:
     92             self.log_request_fail(method, url, body, duration, response.status)
---> 93             self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
     94 
     95         self.log_request_success(method, full_url, url, body, response.status,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.pyc in _raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    103             pass
    104 
--> 105         raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
    106 
    107 

TransportError: TransportError(500, u'not_x_content_exception')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't update the mapping like this in index, you've to create new mapping and assign this mapping as new variable for that else you've to delete the index and update it accordingly.